# Cannot install tools for universal windows apps update

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, uwp

My Visual Studio 2015 notifies me that it has an update:

[image]

When I click on it I see this:

[image]

When I click the update button I get this:

[image]

Note, that the Update button is disabled.

How can I install this update?

**Update**: Apparently multiple people experience a similar issue but so far no resolution: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2015/10/10/10642055.aspx (See comments to the linked blog post)

Comment: I assume you did try to click the `Update` button?  I did an update today and thought the button was disabled, but it actually wan't, just looked like it.

Comment: @JohnieKarr It's been like this a few months. I tried everything, even uninstalling  windows sdk. Did not help... Yes, I did click the button. More than once.

Comment: Hmmm, interesting...I have no clue.  Only thing I can think to try is to close Visual Studio after getting to this point.  It will make you close later in the process anyway.  It's probably safe to assume you have the 10 MB available disk space too, lol

Comment: @JohnieKarr I'm on Win 8.1

Comment: I'm on windows 10 (latest updates) and ran into this today as well, unchecking any box allowed for "Next" but with all selected update was grayed out.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try running this installer (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=627168) to update the UWP tools to v1.1.1.

I had similar issues, this installer update worked. This is “Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 (KB3073097)” version 14.0.23315.

Comment: Yep. The button was labelled repair, I pressed it, it finished, still wanting to update and cannot. Thank you for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install [Visual Studio 2015 Update 1](https://www.visualstudio.com/news/vs2015-update1-vs). This is the latest version of Visual Studio 2015 by now and it contains "Tools for Universal Windows Apps (v1.2)" which is also the latest version.

Although you can use Visual Studio 2015 with Windows 8.1 to create Windows Universal Apps, but when running on OS earlier than Windows 10, some Visual Studio features for Windows Universal development may be degraded, such as you can only use the XAML designer if your development platform is Windows 10. And on Windows 8.1, you can’t run the Windows universal app locally (only on a remote Windows 10 device). You can use the emulators in Visual Studio, but not the simulator. For more information, please see **Requirements** in [Develop apps for the Universal Windows Platform (UWP)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn975273.aspx)

So if you are developing Windows Universal Apps, **Windows 10 is strongly recommended**.

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 was already installed when I posted the question. Did not help =( Thanks.

Comment: @zespri Form the screenshot you've posted, it seems you are still using Visual Studio 2015 not Visual Studio 2015 Update 1. Please check your Visual Studio Version, the latest version is "14.0.24720.00 Update 1". It contains "Tools for Universal Windows Apps (v1.2)", you can enable them by modifying the Visual Studio 2015 installation, or by directly installing them from the following link: [http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=619614](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=619614)

Comment: It seems wrong - I am/was using Visual Studio 2015 Update 1, not Visual Studio 2015. The version is as you say "14.0.24720.00 Update 1". The problem is unfortunately still unresolved.

Answer (score 0):

I should note that I have the same problem and I AM using Windows 10.

The reason the UPDATE button is greyed out is because you cannot update anything. Everything is already installed, along with the latest version. Notice if you uncheck anything, the next button is active allowing you to remove components. Basically it is a bug still showing the update is not installed.

However, you can install a different version of the Windows 10 SDK (v10.0.10586.15 - Nov 2015) versus (v10.0.26624 - July 2015) by downloading it [directly](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk). Remember you should already have [Tools for Universal Windows Apps (v1.2)](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=534599) instead of (v1.1.1).

I'm guessing the bug comes from the fact that the two items can be individually up-to-date, but the developer tools setup file may not be (technically it is v14.0.5806). Also the November SDK version is incorrectly labeled, the correct version should be (v10.1.10586.15). If you look in Programs and Features you can see it labeled two different things. Basically VS does not know the latest version is already installed.

Comment: When you install that, does visual studio stop telling you that you have an update?